# How to find a good photographer/company to make proper passport photos for a Dutch passport issued by a Dutch consulate abroad?

Tags: passport, netherlands, belgium

The Netherlands have photo requirements that differ from those required by the Belgium authorities. Each time I have to renew a passport it is always a big gamble to get proper pictures. On many occasions I had to reschedule because the pictures made by a Belgian professional photographer was considered inappropriate. Apparently the [Dutch instructions](http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/paspoort-en-identificatie/documenten-en-publicaties/brochures/2014/02/18/fotomatrix-2007.html) aren't detailed enough for a foreign photographer to make good pictures.

Currently I simply drive to the Netherlands to make those pictures there, but that is not really convenient, and I can imagine that Dutch citizens abroad are facing similar problems.

Are there standardised instructions on international passport pictures or a listing of foreign photographers, that can result in proper foreign (e.g. Dutch) passport pictures?

Comment: I was faced with a similar problem recently and I found a small local independent photographer who was happy to match the specifications for passport photos published by other countries. He had a binder full of foreign specs that he had collected. I didn't need any Dutch passport pictures, though.

Comment: http://canada.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/v/verenigde_staten_van_amerika/the-royal-netherlands-embassy-in-washington-dc/import/services/consular_services/passport/dutch-passport-photo-requirements---2011.pdf - here are the same specifications in english. IMHO they are detailed enough.

Answer (score 2):

The Dutch consulate general in New York recommends a nearby photographer.  When the consulate moved a year or two ago, they started recommending a different photographer who was nearby the new location.